# Get the active shipping methods and rates custom checkout page?

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods

We have integrate the custom checkout page. I will try to get the shipping methods and rates. I used the below code get all shipping methods but i want shipping cost also. How to get the shipping rates of the customer address

```
public function getActiveShippingMethods(){

        $activeCarriers = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();


        $allCarriers = array();

        foreach($activeCarriers as $carrierCode => $carrierModel){
            $options = array();

            if( $carrierMethods = $carrierModel->getAllowedMethods() ){

                $carrierTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$carrierCode.'/title');
                foreach ($carrierMethods as $methodCode => $method) {
                    $code= $carrierCode.'_'.$methodCode;

                    $options[]=array('value'=>$code,'label'=>$carrierTitle.' '.$method);
                    $allCarriers[] = array('value'=>$code,'label'=>$carrierTitle.' '.$method,'label_disp'=>$carrierMethods[$methodCode]);

                }

            }
            $methods[]=array('value'=>$options,'label'=>$carrierTitle);
        }

         return $allCarriers;
    }
```